# Determine whether the given series is absolutely convergent or conditionally convergent

Tags: trigonometry, summation, logarithms, absolute-convergence, conditional-convergence

> Consider the series
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log\left(1+\frac{1}{|\sin(n)|}\right).$$
>   Determine whether it converges **absolutely** or **conditionally**.

I am trying to apply **Cauchy condensation test**, but I am not sure whether the given series is non-increasing or not.

Comment: Can you prove it converges at all?

Comment: It can't converge. The limit as $n \to \infty$ doesn't equal zero. In fact, the minimum of the equation being summed up is $\log(2) \approx .30103$. Therefore, the series diverges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the term $\log\left(1+\frac{1}{|\sin(n)|}\right)$ is not decreasing, but since  $|\sin(x)|\leq 1$, it follows that
$$ \log\left(1+\frac{1}{|\sin(n)|}\right)\geq \log\left(1+\frac{1}{1}\right).$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: And  log(1+1/n ) diverges . It can be checked by comparing it with 1/n.

Comment: @blueboy Actually a stronger estimate holds.

Comment: Yes. Thanks ...